# Filtering rows on numeric values of a certain number of columns in dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a  dataframe called `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  gene = c("ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL"),
  data_set_a= c(0.15,0.00001,0.5,0.0002),
  data_set_b= c(0.68,0.21,0.35,0.2),
  data_set_c= c(0.1,0.00001,0.52,0.00007),
  data_set_d= c(0.33,0.00001,0.5,0.06),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

I selected the rows where the all numerical values are lower than 0.001:

```
library(tidyverse)
common <- df %>% filter_if(is.numeric, all_vars(. < 0.001))
```

This returns an empty dataframe as there are no rows where all the numerical values are lower than 0.001.
Is there a way to change the filter to select *n* numerical values instead of all?

Comment: Many ways. For instance `rowSums(df[-1]<0.001)` gives how many values each row has less than 0.001. You can filter based on that.

Comment: Thank you, I did not think of that!